# Do I need a transit visa to travel from US to India via Europe

Tags: usa, visas, transit, airport-security, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen planning to go to India via London or Frankfurt. I won't go outside of airport. I heard rumor that you need a transit visa due to changes in European policies. Is this true ? Does it make sense at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Indian citizens usually need a transit visa even if you are going to stay airside, but if you have a valid US visa, you will not need a transit visa in most cases. It shouldn't be too hard to obtain, so don't despair.

There are some more exceptions for this rule which you may qualify for:

[For London](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/nonustransit.html)
[For Frankfurt](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html)

Comment: Wow this is new! The last I traveled in 2012, only france needed a transit visa for Indians!