# Travelling from US to India via Brussels with Jet Airways , do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, brussels, h1b-visas

Travelling from US to India via Brussels with Jet Airways , do I need a transit visa?

I-94 Expired
Visa Expired
Valid H1-B pettion till 2017

Comment: What is your country of residence? What is your country of passport? What is your citizenship?

Comment: Nationality: India
passport : India

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13430/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-to-travel-from-us-to-india-via-europe?rq=1

Comment: @DJClayworth Thanks went through above site but dint get from it for Brussels. Thanks for sharing above links.

Comment: Brussels is part of the [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) for which all visa rules are essentially the same.